# Convert a C# Method to return a boolean from a lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

The following obviously will not compile, so what should I change?

```
public bool IsFoobar(bool foo, bool bar)
{
    return db.Foobars.SingleOrDefault(fb => ((fb.foo == foo) && (fb.bar == bar)));
}
```

Comment: What should the function do, and what is the type of the `FooBars` collection?

Comment: "obviously will not compile..." maybe my telepathy powers are on the blink, but it's not obvious to me! What if `fb` has a conversion to `bool`?

Comment: One that was made up in order to ask this question ;->

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try

```
public bool IsFoobar(bool foo, bool bar)
{
    return db.Foobars.Any(fb => fb.foo == foo && fb.bar == bar);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gaute and everyone else.

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing how your datamodel looks and how you actually wish this to behave, I'd hazard a guess at

```
public bool IsFoobar(bool foo, bool bar)
{
    return db.Foobars.SingleOrDefault(fb => ((fb.foo == foo) && (fb.bar == bar))) != null;
}
```

**Edit:**
While you could use `.Any` as the other poster said, by using `!= null` you'd still get the exception thrown if your database has two matching rows. However, if you do not want that check you should probably use the suggested `.Any` method instead.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are looking for [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx):

```
return db.Foobars.Any(fb => ((fb.foo == foo) && (fb.bar == bar)));
```

Comment: How is this different from Gaute Magnussen's earlier answer?

Comment: @ChrisF, It isn't. He was faster and I didn't saw it.

Comment: Sorry for sounding a bit harsh but I'm getting a bit annoyed about duplicate answers, and yours was the first I've seen since I decided I'd comment when I see them. I'll try to come up with a more tactful phrase.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve here but to break it down in to parts that may help, firstly you could define the lambda as (assuming `db.FooBars` is a collection of type `FooBar`):

```
bool foo = ...someBooleanValue...;
bool bar = ...someOtherBooleanValue...;

Func<FooBar, bool> myTest = fb => ((fb.foo == foo) && (fb.bar == bar));
```

OR without including the foo and bar values in the closure:

```
Func<FooBar, bool, bool, bool> myTest = 
                 (fb, foo, bar) => ((fb.foo == foo) && (fb.bar == bar));
```

and then get a result on a particular instance of `FooBar` via (using the 1st lambda example):

```
FooBar myFooBar = ...some instance...;

bool result = myTest(myFooBar);
```

OR using the second lambda example:

```
FooBar myFooBar = ...some instance...;
bool foo = ...someBooleanValue...;
bool bar = ...someOtherBooleanValue...;

bool result = myTest(myFooBar, foo, bar);
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

This is unlikely to be the answer, but it's perhaps important to realise that the original code could compile fine given the right definitions preceding it:

```
// Ugh! Public data for brevity

class Foobar
{
    public bool foo, bar;
    public static implicit operator bool(Foobar fb) { return fb.foo; }
}

class Db
{
    public IEnumerable<Foobar> Foobars;
}

Db db;
```

Now the original code compiles fine:

```
public bool IsFoobar(bool foo, bool bar)
{
    return db.Foobars.SingleOrDefault(fb => ((fb.foo == foo) && (fb.bar == bar)));
}
```

But admittedly it would probably be better if it didn't.